# Scrollview is not working in python kivy app

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, scrollview, scrollbar

I will need so much buttons and rows in my app I need scrollbar and scroll view in my other program scrolling is working but in this it is not working

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


class Program(App):
    def build(self):

        self.main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")

        self.firstrow = BoxLayout( size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        self.secondrow = BoxLayout( size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        #Actually there are so many rows thats why I need scrollview but I show you brief
        self.grid_izgara=GridLayout( cols=5, spacing=10, padding=10, size_hint_y=None )

        self.scroll_view = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 900))
        self.grid_izgara.bind(minimum_height=self.grid_izgara.setter("height"))
        self.eqn = Label(text= "Equation")
        self.equation = TextInput( size_hint_y=None, height=44)

        self.buton = Button(text="Drop Down Menu", size_hint_y=None, height=44)

        self.lowerBound = Label(text="Lower Bound", size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        self.lowerB = TextInput()
        self.upperBound = Label(text="Upper Bound", size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        self.upperB = TextInput()

        self.maxIteration = Label(text="Max Iteration", size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        self.maxI = TextInput()
        self.tolerance = Label(text="Toleration")
        self.toler = TextInput()

        self.solveButon = Button(text="Solve It")

        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="bir", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="iki", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="uc", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="dort", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="bes", size_hint_y=None, height=44))

        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="birsıfırw", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="ikisıfıwr", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="ucsıfıwr", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="dortsıfıwr", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        self.grid_izgara.add_widget(Button(text="bessıfırw", size_hint_y=None, height=44))
        # Actually there are so many buttons thats why I need scrollview but I show you brief

        self.firstrow.add_widget(self.eqn)
        self.firstrow.add_widget(self.equation)

        self.secondrow.add_widget(self.solveButon)

        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.firstrow)
        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.buton)
        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.secondrow)

        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.grid_izgara)#Besinci Satırı ekledik
        self.scroll_view.add_widget(self.main_layout)
        return self.scroll_view



Program().run()
```

I prefer solving this problem with only python code without builder and .kv file. I can not handle them easily because of my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `minimum_height` for the `main_layout`, just as you did for the `grid_izgara`. Like this:

```
    self.main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", size_hint_y=None)
    self.main_layout.bind(minimum_height=self.main_layout.setter('height'))
```